# How to share data for all pages with help @extends @section @yield in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

How to share data for all pages with help `@extends` `@section` `@yield` in Laravel? For example, there is 1 controller. It displays all news, all comments, all users. This controller inherits the main layer (`layouts.app`). How do I make all other pages inherit this data?

*How to make the other.blade.php page have data from the main.blade.php page? A simple example:*

```
// layouts.app.blade.php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    ...
</head>
<body>
    @yield('one')
    @yield('two')
    @yield('content')
</html>


//main.blade.php
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('one')
    // dynamic content
@endsection

@section('two')
    // dynamic content
@endsection


//other.blade.php
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    // dynamic content
@endsection
```

Comment: Please show us what you tried and where you had any issues. SO doesn't code for you, it helps solving problems.

Comment: If you want to insert data to all your views, then ry using service providers. If you can provide more exact info, then we can help more

Comment: How to make the other.blade.php page have data from the main.blade.php page? A simple example:https://pastebin.com/5JzTSwPH

Answer (score 0):

Answering to your question about how to share data on components you can read the [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#extending-a-layout) about blade templating:

> Passing Additional Data To Components
>
> Sometimes you may need to pass additional data to a component. For
>   this reason, you can pass an array of data as the second argument to
>   the @component directive. All of the data will be made available to
>   the component template as variables:
>
> @component('alert', ['foo' => 'bar'])
>       ... @endcomponent

Example:

```
@extends('view', ['data_1' => 1, 'data_2' => 2])
```

OR

```
@include('view', ['title'=> 'Example of include'])
```

About your blade structure question I would do like this:

```
// layouts.app.blade.php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    ...
</head>
<body>
    @yield('one')
    @yield('two')
    @yield('content')
</html>


//main.blade.php
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('one')
    // dynamic content
@endsection

@section('two')
    // dynamic content
@endsection

@include('other.blade.php', ["data" => 'your_data'])

//other.blade.php

@section('content')
    // dynamic content
@endsection
```

The problem on this is depending on your App the blade structure can vary a lot, so maybe is so extensive question to answer here.

Comment: Add it on the main question, not as a comment in a answer.

Comment: How to make the other.blade.php page have data from the main.blade.php page? A simple example: https://pastebin.com/5JzTSwPH

Comment: Done! Please check.